# Can I disable Win10 S mode support to pass the Windows Store review?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, electron

As title, I have an electron-based app with some native npm dep. And one of then (sharp) didn't pass the Windows Store review because of crash on Win10 S mode. I can't find an option to disable Win10 S mode support in dev console, and I asked MS review team twice, no any response. I can't drop the dep because it's core function. If the app just show a 'not support' page when Win10 S mode, can it pass the review? Or there are some way to disable Win10 S mode support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you plan to publish your application to the Microsoft Store, make sure that your application operates correctly on devices that run Windows 10 S. This is a Store requirement.

You could see this requirement in the official document:[Distribute your application by publishing it to the Microsoft Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-distribute#distribute-your-application-by-publishing-it-to-the-microsoft-store)